# Problems to upgrade from 18.04.5 to 20.04 LTS, again!

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.5 in one of my desktop PCs.

Since a week, the system is offering me the chance to upgrade to the last 20.04 LTS, but...

When I ask the system to perform the upgrading, the system tells me that I have to upgrade all the packages of my today (18.04.5) version before to upgrade to the last 20.04 LTS.

The only one package I know I could to upgrade is WineHQ. But, that package is hold to the 18.04.5 version, I don't know why.

So... My simple question is: If I uninstalled the WineHQ package, Will be able to upgrade all the system to the last 20.04 LTS version?

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much to all!

I could solve the problem uninstalling WineHQ.

Now I have the last 20.04 LTS version installed.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to do this, in `terminal`...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`reboot`

Then start `Software Updater`. Boom.